# Is there any way I can get hard drive data in UWP?

Tags: c#, c++, uwp

Is there any way to read physical drive sectors in UWP app. Something like WinApi CreateFile/ReadFile function that won't need administrator privileges.

Comment: May I know what the physical drive you are referring to? Is it the SD card or HD? Currently, there is no way to get some low-level data, that is, to read the data of the sectors. We can only get the specific file or folder with path and use Windows.Storage.FileIO to read and write files.

Comment: Physical drive sector access requires administrator privileges because it lets you bypass security.